# Using Django URLs with other than HTTP

Tags: django

How do I get Django to respond to a new protocol?  For example, instead of http://example.com, I would like to have Django server a page in response to new_protocol://example.com

Comment: Django is a web framework. I don't think it can respond to non web protocols unless through a proxy of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

on the following link is explained

http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2009/02/18/securing-django-with-ssl/